# Show a dataset inside a picker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am new in react native. I need to read some data from a file.js and shows them inside the Picker. I need just the "Title" inside the picker. 
Here is my file.js:

```
export const mydata = [
       {
       "id": 1,
       "Title": "Shiraz"
       "prop": [
                  {
                    "id": 1,
                    "Title": "Test1",
                  }
               ]
       },
];
```

My picker code is as below:

```
import {mydata} from "./myfile.js";

                         <Picker
                             style={{flex:1}}
                             data={mydata}
                             mode="dropdown"
                             selectedValue={this.state.PickerValueHolder}
                             onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setState({PickerValueHolder: itemValue})} >
                             {
                               data.map((item, index) => {
                               return (<Item label={item} value={index} key={index}/>) 
                                  }
                                )
                              }
                        </Picker>
```

In the above code the data is not defined and I don't know how to manage it in such a way, that it shows the file content correctly. 
Can you help me how can I show my "Title" data inside the picker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change your function depending on the data you want to display. e.g. your data looks like that

```
export const mydata = [
   {
   "id": 1, // will be shown as value
   "Title": "Shiraz" // will be shown as your label 
   "prop": [
              {
                "id": 1,
                "Title": "Test1",
              }
           ]
   },
   "id": 2, // will be shown as value
   "Title": "Shiraz2" // will be shown as your label 
   "prop": [
              {
                "id": 1,
                "Title": "Test1",
              }
           ]
   },
   ];
```

Then you need to change your component to:

```
    <Picker
    >
       {this.renderPickerItems(mydata)}
   </Picker>
```

and i would recommend to create a new function to render items:

```
renderPickerItems(data) {
    const elements = data.map((val, index) => {
        return <Picker.Item key={index} label={val.Title} value={val.id} /> 
    });
    return elements; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the same error happen! I think, my method is not a correct way to show data in picker. Do you have any idea about that?

Comment: yes your data is not correctly formatted. Which information do you want to show inside the picker? e.g. do you want to have  "Shiraz" to be displayed and as value id = 1 ?

Comment: I need to show just the content of "Title" inside my picker. So, it means that, in my case only the word "Shiraz" should show inside the picker.

Comment: @Reza did it work ? If yes, please accept my answer as correct.

Comment: @ Sorry for my delay. It shows and error: 'Type error: cannot read property map of undefined'

Comment: what appens if you console.log 'data' insde renderPickerItems function and inside your picker component ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159758/discussion-between-reza-and-timh).